# Intellij PHP remote debugging: Failed to execute validation script

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I am trying to configure the PHP remote debugging feature of the PHP plugin in IntelliJ. When I try to validate my configuration I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute validation script:
'Could not read from "host:port/path/to/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php"
because it is not a file.'
```

I don't really know where the problem is. I assume this php file is something that IntelliJ copies to the remote server and then tries to execute. But for some reason that fails. Can anyone provide some insight what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: If you actually put "host" for the remote hostname, that would be the problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem appears if the 'Web Path' field under Tools | Deployment | Configuration | Mapping is not correctly pointing to the url at which the uploaded validator script is accessible.

Comment: How did you figure out where that was?

Comment: can you advise which is the correct path as I have added the file manually and every time I try to run the script it gets deleted and I get "failed to execute validation script :'Status 404' even after following Intellij tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Just download file

http://gist.github.com/litzinger/8fd06ab6e5033b7ff8d8

to your deployment directory or directly to target server document root directory

Comment: Here is the same file in another gist: https://gist.github.com/litzinger/8fd06ab6e5033b7ff8d8

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue is the Apache Rewrite rules that when _intellij_phpdebug_validator.php get the redirect file in my case to a 404 page of Symfony framework installed for this project.